# WPF TextBlock Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Помогите разобраться, не понимаю как отладить код или почему он не работает.

Есть окно, в котором есть класс, создаваемый в конструкторе.

```
public class mainWindow : Window
{
   private readonly Class1 _cls1 = new Class1();
   public Class1 cls1
   {
        get
        {
             return _cls1;
        }
   }
}
```

Class1 - это наследник от BaseClass

```
public class Class1 : BaseClass
{

}
```

BaseClass это наследник DepencesObject в котором определено свойство DependencyProperty

```
public class BaseClass : DepencesObject
{
    public string Field
    {
       get{return(string)Getvalue(FieldProperty);}
       set{SetValue(FieldProperty, value);}
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FieldProperty = DependencyProperty.register("Field", typeof(string), typeof(string));
}
```

В XAML формы прописано:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding cls1.Field}"/>
```

Но или не проходит привязка, или не обновляются данные из Field (на момент создания формы там "")

В чем я ошибся?

Comment: А что там должно быть на момент создания? Где запись в `cls1` идет? Как UI должен узнать, что `cls1` обновилось?

Comment: @Андрей запись идет при вызове определенного метода. Назовем его mainWindow.Load() {cls1.Field = "Текст";}

Comment: `cls1 = new ...` - где?

Comment: И DataContext установлен?

Comment: @Андрей, Обновил код mainWindow. Создание класса происходит в конструкторе.

Comment: @Андрей, нет, DataContext не установлен, но на сколько я понял, он не обязателен

Comment: DataContext нужен, без него не будет работать. Или всему окну или текстовому полю установите. Или непосредственно в привязке укажите.

Comment: Сделал инициализации поля не пустым значением, данные из поля попадают в textblock.text через привязку, но не обновляются при изменения значения. Может быть проблема в наследовании?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас ошибка:

```
DependencyProperty.register("Field", typeof(string), typeof(string));
```

Это неверно, нужно

```
DependencyProperty.Register("Field", typeof(string), typeof(BaseClass));
```

Не создавайте `DependencyProperty` вручную, пользуйте сниппетом `propdp`.